# Conditional expression in Angular.js templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to build a monthly calendar using Angular.js, and I can't seem to find a way of outputting expressions when conditions are satisfied.

```
  <tr>
    <td ng-repeat="date in dates">
      {{date}}
    </td>
    {{'</tr><tr>' | if date.getDay() === 0}}
  </tr>
```

Or

```
  <tr>
    <td ng-repeat="date in dates">
      {{date}}
      {{ if date.getDay() === 0 expr = '</tr><tr>' else expr = ''}}
    </td>
    {{expr}}
  </tr>
```

How could I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Your code implies your date to be an object.  If so, {{date}} would render the string representation of that object.

Comment: I just copied some example code from my project, it doesn't matter if it's a date object.

Comment: @fdomig answer is a good choice.  Use ng-repeat.  If your collection needs filtering, add a filter in the ng-repeat.

Comment: That's what I did, but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I think you are set on one specific direction.  You can solve your issue by taking an alternative that might be cleaner and easier to read.  You should let the data drive the DOM without trying to manipulate the DOM markup directly.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the built in `ng-if` directive.

```
<tr ng-if="date.getDay() === 0">
```

The better solution could be a nested `ng-repeat` so you don't even have to do these checks. For instance:

```
<tr ng-repeat="week in weeks">
    <td ng-repeat="day in week.days">...</td>
</td>
```

Comment: I can't use ng-if, because adding a tr tag wouldn't help me, I need to close the tag and open it, so I can get to the next row.

Comment: You can use the `ng-if` in both, the `<tr>` and `</tr>` tag.

Comment: To add to @fdomig, add a filter to filter days that getDay() return zero.